# How to do a full text search with Nhibernate and get result ranks?

Tags: nhibernate, full-text-search

I have a SQL 2008 R2 database with full text indexing set up and would like to use NHibernate to get back search results with ranking.  I've figured out the SQL queries usng FULLTEXTTABLE to get result rankings, but I'm struggling with how to use NHibernate to get results with the ranking value since it doesn't map to an actual column in any table.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

(First of all the following syntax will be a bit hazy because this is from memory, please check the api)

well you can either construct some DTO class and map that on-the-fly

for example:

```
public class Person
{
     public virtual String Name {get;set;}
     public virtual String Surname {get;set;}
}
```

which is properly mapped to nhibernate
and the

```
PersonDTO : Person
{
    public int FTSRanking {get;set;}
}
```

which is not mapped. Note that i'm inheriting from class `Person` although that is not necessary and i'm only doing it for ease.
This `PersonDTO` class is only used on queries but there are limitations, as the following hql shows.

```
NHSes.CreateQuery('select p.Name, p.Surname, p.FTSAlias as FTSRanking from Person p')
     .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<PersonDTO>())
```

will return a PersonDTO which nhibernate manages to assemble because every item in the select list matches a property (in name, casing, type) in the PersonDTO class. Also you will have to manually type the select list and also, since it is not a mapped class, nhibernate cannot assemble collections.

An other option would be to use the Criteria API in which you set projections (aka extend the select list)

```
IList<object[]> results = NHSes.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
         .Add(Expression.SQL(" your fts clause here "))
         .SetProjection(Projections.SQL(" add your fts ranking column here",,), Projections.( here add as a projection the main entity ))
         .List<object[]>();
```

where in the results variable each returned row is an object[] and the first element (ie results[0][0]) is the ranking and the second element (ie results[0][1]) is a properly managed Person object

Comment: `.Add(Expression...)` will add it to the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query, but `FULLTEXTTABLE` is something you typically use in the `FROM` clause.